# Create Relative Symlink Inside Relative Symlink

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, symlink

I've been browsing for a minute now trying to find a way to create a relative symlink inside a relative symlink, and what I mean by that is this...

I have my CakePHP Templates Skeleton as a symlink inside one of my projects, inside my skeleton, I have a symlink to a plugin outside the skeleton folder, the idea being, I can symlink my CakePHP CMS Skeleton inside my projects, create an "Application" plugin outside the CMS skeleton symlink, and and the skeleton symlink point to my projects "Application" plugin.

By that I mean the following.

I have a CakePHP CMS Skeleton at the following path

```
/mnt/proj/libs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel
```

The path to my project folder is below

```
/mnt/proj/mysite.com/
```

I then symlink the CakePHP CMS Skeleton inside my project folder like so

```
/mnt/proj/mysite.com/cms-skel -> /mnt/proj/libs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel
```

Inside the skeleton I have a symlink pointing to an Application plugin

```
/mnt/proj/libs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel/Plugin/Application -> ../../Application
```

So inside the CakePHP CMS symlinked folder in mysite.com folder I have

```
/mnt/proj/mysite.com/cms-skel/Plugin/Application -> ../../Application
```

The issue is, that the above symlink points to

```
/mnt/proj/libs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/Application
```

And I need it to point to

```
/mnt/proj/mysite.com/cms-skel/Plugin/Application
```

Any ideas on how I can do the above with symlinks is greatly appreciate, I am not even sure what to google at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You issue is you're attempting to use a single relative link that will work within 2 directory trees, and yet the relativity of the link is not the same in these 2 trees.

#### Example

I've created your directory structures starting at `proj`, but otherwise they're identical.

```
$ pwd
/home/saml/proj
```

Here's the `lib/` tree:

```
$ tree -lf libs/
libs
`-- libs/cakephp
    `-- libs/cakephp/lib
        `-- libs/cakephp/lib/Cake
            `-- libs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console
                `-- libs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Templates
                    |-- libs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/Application
                    `-- libs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel
                        `-- libs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel/Plugin
                            `-- libs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel/Plugin/Application -> ../../Application  [recursive, not followed]
```

Here's the `mysite.com/` tree:

```
$ tree -lf mysite.com/
mysite.com
`-- mysite.com/cms-skel -> /home/saml/proj/libs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel/
    `-- /home/saml/proj/libs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel//Plugin
        `-- /home/saml/proj/libs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel//Plugin/Application -> ../../Application
```

So if we were to look at the Application link in the 1st tree, `lib/`:

```
$ pwd
/home/saml/proj/libs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel/Plugin

$ readlink -f Application
/home/saml/proj/libs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/Application
```

However, if we do the same analysis in the `mysite.com/` directory we see our problem.

```
$ pwd
/home/saml/proj/mysite.com/cms-skel/Plugin

$ readlink -f Application
/home/saml/proj/libs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/Application
```

#### What's going on?

Well when you're in the `mysite.com/` tree 2 levels above `mysite.com/cms-skel/Plugin/` is `libs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Templates`.

This should help to see it:

```
$ pwd
/home/saml/proj/mysite.com/cms-skel/Plugin

$ readlink -f ../../
/home/saml/proj/libs/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Templates
```

I do not see a way around this given the differences in the number of directories within the 2 trees.